# How to print a specific actionerror message with Struts2 validation?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, struts-validation

When using Struts2 validation, when you put the `<s:actionerror>` tag in your JSP, the default behavior is to display all the action errors at that point in the page.

Is there a way to display only specific error messages at that point?  For example, in the case of `fielderror` one only needs to add the `fieldName` attribute.  Is there an attribute of `actionerror` that accomplishes similar behavior?

Comment: But, by definition, actionErrors are "global", while fieldErrors are associated to fields. (You can think of actionErrors as Collection<String>, and fieldErrors as Map<String,Collection<String>> )

And recall that the (programmatic) way of generating actionErrors is Action.addActionError(String)

So, I don't imagine what you mean by "display only specific error messages".
Specific how?

Answer (score 2):

For field specific error the function is : `hasFieldErrors()`

You can use it like this:

```
<s:if test="hasFieldErrors()">
    <div class="fieldErrors">
        <!-- iterate through the fields errors, customize what you need -->
        <s:iterator value="fieldErrors">
            <s:property value="key"/>:
            <s:iterator value="value">
                <s:property/>
            </s:iterator>
        </s:iterator>
    </div>
</s:if>
```

*References:*

- [Struts 2 documentation](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/interceptor/ValidationAware.html).

*Interesting reading:*

- [Why are my actionErrors and fieldErrors displayed with braces []?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44948426/628006)
- https://www.mkyong.com/struts2/working-with-struts-2-theme-template/

Comment: I'll upvote your contribution.  I'll not accept, because I'm not in a position to determine if this provides what I need.  The project is finished, and I work for a different company.