# Why are my actionErrors and fieldErrors displayed with braces []?

Tags: jsp, struts2

Once the pages have captured errors within my Struts 2 application the errors are displayed correctly from my resource bundles however they are always displayed with a braces `[]`.

**For example:**

```
[first name must not be empty]
```

These are displayed through the tags:

```
<s:actionerror />

<s:iterator value="fieldErrors">
   <s:property value="value" />
</s:iterator>
```

These come through the `Action-validation.xml` and setting a `addFieldError()` through the validation method

Is this something to do with my theme being set to `simple` ? I can't see anything in documentation or anything through other posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why

No, it is not about theme. Take a look at `getFieldErrors` method. It returns map where value is a list of strings.

```
public Map<String, List<String>> getFieldErrors() {
    return validationAware.getFieldErrors();
}
```

Your code iterates over map and `value` is a list. List as string will be displayed with surrounding braces.

#### How

If you need only value of the error message and not the key then you can use `addActionError` method instead and iterate over `actionErrors`.

If you want to iterate `fieldErrors` then you can do it like that.

```
<s:iterator value="fieldErrors">
    <s:property value="key"/>:
    <s:iterator value="value">
        <s:property/>
    </s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
```

And of course there are tags for displaying errors/messages, see [Non-Form UI Tags](https://struts.apache.org/docs/tag-reference.html#TagReference-UITags).

Answer (score 0):

Without default `xhtml` theme it would render objects as it's printed `toString()`, i.e. formatting an array with brackets.

> Render field errors if they exists the specific layout of the
>   rendering depends on the theme itself. Empty (null or blank string)
>   errors will not be printed. The field error strings will be html
>   escaped by default.

---

The code to display errors should look like

```
<s:if test="hasFieldErrors()">
   <div class="errors">
      <s:fielderror />
   </div>
</s:if>
```

---